# Bash script that convert any output (text) to json form

Tags: bash

I want to create bash script that it converts output of other scripts (Normally simple text)  in a valid json form. How can I do this ?

Example:

```
awk '/^Mem/ {printf("%u%%", 100*$3/$2);}' <(free -m)
```

command give me used memory. I want to get output in valid jason form.

**Desired output:**

```
 {“Memory”:”80”}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example for memory:

```
echo {\"Memory\":\"$(awk '/^Mem/ {printf("%u", 100*$3/$2);}' <(free -m))\"} > mem.json
```

Putting that new file name into json:

```
echo {\"file\":\"$(ls mem.json)\"} > filename.json
```

Or:

```
echo {\"<paramName-here>\":\"$(<value-of-param-from-command-here>)\"} > mem.json
```

When it gets more complicated than this, you can continue to write line by line or more likely build strings in a variable.

Answer (score 4):

```
free -k | { read 
    read TITLE TOTAL USED REST
    echo "{\"Memory\":\"$(( 100 * $USED / $TOTAL ))\"}"
}
```

The output of free is piped to a compound command consisting of:
A first "read" which skips the first output line of "free".
A second "read" which reads the line we need, we need only the second and third value.
An echo which prints the line in the format you want including the calculation

Comment: That's a totally non-portable method, how could I go if I want to add more complex JSON objects?

Comment: I might have misunderstood you question...you wanted the percentage of free memory in JSON form isn't it ?  If not, please explain in more detail what you expect.

Comment: *"I want to create bash script that it converts output of other scripts (Normally simple text) in a valid json form."* The memory was just an example. With your approach he would need to write a method for each input.

Comment: That is not enough info. You understand of course that the format of the input must be given. Are we talking about something simple like key value pairs for example ? Is there a way the OP can narrow it down a bit ? The question is too fuzzy.

Comment: Of course I don't expect that the OP asks for a full blown parser...in that case he would have asked so.

Answer (score 3):

I created a tool called `jc` that converts the output of many command line tools, inclduing `free` to json:

```
$ jc free | jq
[
  {
    "type": "Mem",
    "total": 3993360,
    "used": 293248,
    "free": 3185992,
    "shared": 1196,
    "buff_cache": 514120,
    "available": 3465280
  },
  {
    "type": "Swap",
    "total": 2097148,
    "used": 0,
    "free": 2097148
  }
]
```

https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc